# What did I get the chameleon hat for?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

It says secret.  I must know what I did!  Something with closing as duplicate maybe?  Or hiding something?  Or I did update my profile today- that might make sense.

Comment: We don't know. And, personally, I don't want to know, because 1) it would spoil me and 2) the meta-questions generated by this whole hat business are getting quite boring.

Comment: Maybe you are two-faced?  :)

Comment: Too meta for me. :|

Comment: If it's a *secret hat*, that means there is no information available about why it's awarded (that's what makes it *secret*).

Comment: I think it has something to do with being active on several different Stack Exchange websites. I got it with my first question to Code Review.

Comment: Maybe you had one hat on, then you switched to a different hat.  (No idea; really just guessing here.)

Answer (score 6):

It's a secret (Shh!)

Remember, a hat is not for life, is just for Christmas - we lose them in a few weeks anyway.
Just a bit of fun.

Perhaps *you* did something specific, perhaps the *ghost of Christmas hats* came *past* and give you as a *present*, perhaps the resident Stack Unicorn likes you...

However you earned it, just enjoy your hat, and enjoy the *mystery* that surrounds the curious way in which it came to you.

Comment: "Remember, a hat is not for life, is just for Christmas"
Noooooooooo :'(

Comment: @Nepoxx "Every" Christmas, tho!!